# Create End_Date column from Start_Date

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table and a column with the Start_Date, with repeats. What query can I use to create a new column that denotes the day after and closest to Start_Date. Example input:

| Start_Date |
| --- |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-03-01 |
| 2021-08-28 |
| 2021-08-28 |
| 2021-05-13 |

Example output:

| Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-05-13 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-05-13 |
| 2021-03-01 | 2021-05-13 |
| 2021-08-28 | Null |
| 2021-08-28 | Null |
| 2021-05-13 | 2021-08-28 |

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will probably work:

```
SELECT t1.start_date,
(SELECT MIN(t2.start_date) end_date
 FROM table1 t2
 WHERE t2.start_date > t1.start_date)
FROM table1 t1
```

Answer (score 0):

A more efficient method might use aggregation and window functions:

```
select t.start_date, tt.end_date
from t join
     (select t.start_date, lead(t.start_date) over (order by t.start_date) as end_date
      from t
      group by t.start_date
     ) tt
     on tt.start_date = t.start_date;
```

It is a little unclear to me why you would have duplicates in the original table.